# custom workflow failed on start

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I have created a simple **sequential workflow**. In this workflow, I am not creating any task. I am just using **code activity** to:

1. send an email to 4 members.
2. wait for their feedback for 5 days.
3. if approved go to the next step.

The problem is that the workflow doesn't hold or wait for 5 days . It crashes within 20 or 30 minutes saying `'failed on start' cancelled by system account`.

If I set that workflow for 30 minutes , it works fine and waits for 30 minutes and go to the next step but if I set it for 1 hour or more than that , it cancels itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sharepoint custom workflow terminates automatically after some time](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166162/sharepoint-custom-workflow-terminates-automatically-after-some-time)