# delayactivity not workfing

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-activity, visual-studio-2013, workflow-manager

I am trying to create a simple sequential workflow using delayactivity. before that i was using hard coded while loop as per : [Custom workflow terminates automatically after some time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166162/sharepoint-custom-workflow-terminates-automatically-after-some-time)

but now still i am facing issues with delayactivity. if i set it to say 5 minutes , after 5 minutes it still shows in progress . and after around 7 or 8 minutes it breaks saying 'error occured'. the logs are:

```
01/05/2016 14:55:26.94  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1D7C)                       0x1EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  88xr    Unexpected  WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# 3b4df44c-371d-40ee-887e-a2a832e0b3ea a139529d-0046-30d1-cd87-54e48628d436
01/05/2016 14:55:26.94  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1D7C)                       0x1EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ADCouncil.Core.ADCouncilServiceProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Failed to Open ADCouncil configuration section. nsure that your configuration is properly set.     at ADCouncil.Core.ADCouncilServiceProvider.LoadConfig()     at ADCouncil.Core.ADCouncilServiceProvider..ctor()     at ADCouncil.Core.ADCouncilServiceProvider..cctor()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at ITPCWorkflow.ITPCWorkflow.ITPCWorkflow.codeActivity2_ExecuteCode(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.RaiseEvent(DependencyProperty dependencyEvent, Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Workflow.Activities.CodeActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflo... a139529d-0046-30d1-cd87-54e48628d436
01/05/2016 14:55:26.94* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1D7C)                       0x1EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  ...w.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()  a139529d-0046-30d1-cd87-54e48628d436
01
```

I followed some other blogs for the similar issue , i did change the workflow-service timeout as per these blogs :
http://the-simple-programmer.blogspot.ae/2012/10/sharepoint-workflow-delay-activity.html
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424946(v=office.12).aspx

it didn't workout .
then I followed other blogs and set the cache.ini to 1 removing all of the xml files . still didn't work.

I am using visual studio 2013, workflow manager is installed , 1 front end development server.
i am setting the 'delayactivity' time from properties window this way:'00:05:00'.

[image: delayactivity]

its just a 3 stage workflow for testing purpose . first activity sends an email to all members , then it should wait for 5 minutes and send another email after 5 minutes .

I am sure its OWSTIMER process issue . but not able to figure out . please suggest something . thanks

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate of the wrong one of your questions. What is the real difference between this question and this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166162/sharepoint-custom-workflow-terminates-automatically-after-some-time ? Just so it is clear to us all what the difference is

Comment: difference is : in the previous post i created a workflow using hard coded "while loop" and workflow was terminating in the middle. so i used "delay activity" in the same workflow to hold the workflow for a specified time . but it is still giving the same errors and breaking before it completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `codeActivity2`, you probably create an instance of class `ADCouncilServiceProvider`. According to my understanding, this class needs some special configuration in the .config file of the process running the code. In case of a WF, the hosting process may be:

- W3WP: in that case, the config file is the famous web.config file.
- OWSTIMER.EXE (aka SharePoint Timer service): OWSTIMER hosts the code after a `Delay` activity for example. In that case, the config file is `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG` as I stated in [Custom workflow terminates automatically after some time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166162/sharepoint-custom-workflow-terminates-automatically-after-some-time/166167#166167). Note: you need to restart the SharePoint Timer service after modifiying that `OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG` file.

[EDIT]
To address your comment about the big picture of your WF:

You have to use a state-machine WF. Maybe with only one main state.

In this main state, at the Init phase, you send emails and create the tasks (I don't see how your x members do approve without tasks ; a task is a communication mean from the users to SharePoint ; you can use other means, but the task is the SharePoint built-in one).

In the Event phase of the state, you listen for two events:

- first the `Delay`. Once the delay has expired: email to who you want, and transition to the final state.
- The other event listens to task modifications: each time a user approves, you check whether all users have approved or not. If they've all approved, email to who you want and transition to final state.

Comment: thank you very much frnd . its working fine if i set to 5 minutes . still a long way to go as it has to wait for 5 days as per my requirement . i will set it for some more time and see what it does . will get back to u . thank u very much once again .

Comment: OK, thank you for your feedback. As usual: feel free to mark the answer as "accepted", if it helped you for good :) –

Comment: Ok @Evariste: delayactivity seems to be fine , its working fine if i set it to 1 hour .

Comment: but my requiremnet as i stated last time:1) send email to all(i m not creating any tasks ,just emailing using code activity) (2) check either members approve,(3) if they approve within 5 days , mail to final approver (4) if dont then email to other person .delayactivity will come in handy to hold it for 5 days . but im gonna need to look every one hour maybe , if all members have taken actions or not . my question is if wf is in the delayactivity for 5 days , its not gonna check for the activities done within that time . and i m using sequential wf sorry for confusion. how can i achieve this.